# Traverse an object tree and render a menu tree based on object property condition

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hello I'm trying to create an html menu from a given object like the following and I was wondering if there is a library that can help me traverse the object, instead of reinventing the wheel.

```
var root = {
    category1: {
        depth: 0,
        categories: {
            category1: {
                depth: 1

            },
            category2: {
                depth: 1,
                products: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

            },
            category3: {
                depth: 1,
                categories: {
                    category1: {
                        depth: 2,
                        products: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                    },
                    category2: {
                        depth: 2,
                        products: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
                    },
                    category3: {
                        depth: 2

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    },
    category2: {
        depth: 0,
        category1: {
            depth: 1,
        },
        category2: {
            depth: 1,
            products:[1,2,3,4,5]

        }
    },
    category3: {
        depth: 0,
        category1: {
            depth: 1,

        },
        category2: {
            depth: 1,
            categories: {
                category1: {
                    depth: 2,
                    products: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                },
                category2: {
                    depth: 2,
                    products: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
                },
                category3: {
                    depth: 2

                }

            }

        }
    },
    depth: 0,
    category4: {
        category1: {
            depth: 1,
            products:[1,2,3,4,5]
        },
        category2: {
            depth: 1,
            categories: {
                category1: {
                    depth: 2,
                    products: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                },
                category2: {
                    depth: 2,
                    products: [1, 2]
                },
                category3: {
                    depth: 2

                }

            }

        },
        category3: {
            depth: 1,

        }
    }

};
```

I'm interested in creating menu paths - nodes which their leaf categories have products all other must be discarded and not rendered. Also products can be found in level 1 and 2 categories. And each category has a depth indicator property indicating the level of the category.

For example if a root category has no leaf level category with products it will not be rendered, or a depth 1 category with no leafs with products will also must not be rendered.

Comment: what means menu? a list?

Comment: a menu with nested submenus yes a list